# servers not working on Linux mint

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

i just started using Linux mint and installed Minecraft on in only to find that when i went on Hypixle every time i change lobby it says `Internal Exception  java.io.IOException: Error while write(...): Broken pipe` i am new to Linux and don't know if this is a common problem.

Comment: How are you connecting to the Hypixel Server? Also, if you are using any mods (even local mods such as optifine), you should remove those and check if you are still having connection issues. If this has helped, try adding them back one after one to see if one of those is the culprit.

Comment: i am using optifine but it still does the same thing if i dont use it still comes up with the same error